# Regexp truncating on "in" word in named capturing group in case-insensitive mode

Tags: regex, pcre

I have regexp:

```
/(t0|t1)\.(?<column>(.*?))\s*(?<opt>(=|>=|<=|<|>|IN|LIKE))\s*(?<search>(.*|$))/i
```

which is supposed to tokenize where clauses generated by a class so I feed them to external webservice. In case-sensitive mode it works fine, but not in case-insensitive mode. please check the demo below .

If there is "in" word the name capturing group truncates work there e.g for

```
t0.date_finished > 'somedate'
```

I am expecting

> [column => date_finished ]

instead I get

> [column => date_f ]

What I am missing ?

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF9fB0/1)

Comment: If there is always space before and after `=|>=|<=|<|>|IN|LIKE` then you do this  `\s+(?<opt>(=|>=|<=|<|>|IN|LIKE))\s+`.

Comment: @velblúd thanks that makes sense

Comment: @velblúd please make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries *only* around `IN` and `LIKE` in the `opts` group:

```
(t0|t1)\.(?<column>.*?)\s*(?<opt>>=|<=|=|<|>|\b(?:IN|LIKE)\b)\s*(?<search>.*)
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM1qM7/3).

Also, you need no capturing groups inside named capturing groups, I removed them in my suggested pattern.

If you put `\b` word boundaries around the non-word sequences will only match after and before word chars (`\b=\b` will match a `=` in a `word1=word1` string).

Note that the longer alternatives in the `opt` group must go before shorter ones.

Also, the `opt` group can be optimized with character classes:

```
(t0|t1)\.(?<column>.*?)\s*(?<opt>[><]=|[=<>]|\b(?:IN|LIKE)\b)\s*(?<search>.*)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where `[><]=|[=<>]` matches either a `>=` or `<=` (the `[><]=` part) or (`|`) a `=`, `<`, or `>`.

Comment: Thanks for the better answer with fine explanation.